# Avoiding spark broadcast join timeouts

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a small DF that is quite expensive to compute. I then broadcast join the small DF with a much larger DF.

The code looks something like:

```scala
    val laregDf = loadLargeDfFromHive()

    // Cached for later re-use
    val smallDf = expensiveComputation().cache()

    val joined = largeDf.as("a").join(broadcast(smallDf.as("b")), $"a.key" === $"b.key", "inner")
```

Now on the cluster I occasionally exceed the broadcast join timeout threshold of `300s`. I could increase this threshold however picking a value is rather arbitrary and I may still exceed the timeout if the cluster is busy.

Would it be better to trigger an action such as `smallDf.count` so that the broadcast does not have to wait for `smallDf` to be computed? Are there any disadvantages with this approach?

Cheers.

Terry

Answer (score 0):

You can use .count or .reduce for caching the dataframe which will make sure you are not doing expensive computation while doing broadcast join